# Using a simple pipeline unix

Tags: c, unix, pipeline

For some reason I can't get it right, I want to call "ls -l" and "tail -n 2" through a pipeline so the last two files in the list of files would show.
Here is the code:

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);
int id = fork();

if(id == 0)
{
    dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execvp("ls", (char*[]){"ls", "-l", NULL});
}
else 
{
    dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
    execvp("tail", (char*[]){"tail", "-n", "2", NULL});
    waitpid(id, NULL, 0);
    close(pipefd[0]);
}

return 0;
```

What is the problem in the following code ? I feel like I have a misunderstanding here, I also searched a lot and no answer was found on the internet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling this:

`dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
 close(pipefd[1]);`

in the child process you are closing the already closed `pipefd[1]`, so `close(pipefd[1]);` has no effect. You should also close `pipefd[0]` in the child process. Same applies to the parent process. So, your code should be edited as below:

```
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);
int id = fork();

if(id == 0)
{
    dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    execvp("ls", (char*[]){"ls", "-l", NULL});
}
else 
{
    dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    execvp("tail", (char*[]){"tail", "-n", "2", NULL});
    waitpid(id, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Working, I understood my problem

Comment: What about 3 processes, by the way?

Comment: Well, the idea stays the same. If you tell me what do you want to do with those 3 processes, I'll try to help.

Comment: Let's say one ls -l, one tail -n 12, one tail -n 2.

Comment: You can create 2 pipes instead of 1 and direct the read/write ends accordingly. For example, first child calls "ls -l" writes it to parent, then parents read that from the first child, run "tail -n 12" and writes it to the second child using the second pipe, and the second child calls "tail -n 2". I implemented it here:
http://www.codeshare.io/OSTXB
(Note: I've never used codeshare before, so if you encounter any problem viewing that link let me know.)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tail` with `cat`, and You'll see list of files is passed and printed by `cat`, but there is no EOF reached. You need to close unused pipefd descriptors:

Note, that `waitpid` in this program is reached only in case `execvp` of `tail` fails.

Fixed code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int pipefd[2];
   pipe(pipefd);
   int id = fork();

   if(id == 0)
   {
      dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
      close(pipefd[0]);
      close(pipefd[1]);
      printf( "child fd = %d\n", fileno(stdout) );
      execvp("ls", (char*[]){"ls", "-l", NULL});
   }
   else 
   {
      dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
      close(pipefd[0]);
      close(pipefd[1]);
      execvp("tail", (char*[]){"tail", "-n", "2", NULL});
/*    execvp("cat", (char*[]){"cat", NULL});*/
      waitpid(id, NULL, 0);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: As per documentation, `dup2` dosn't close original descriptor, both descriptors are usable (but refer to the same file) after successful call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (notice the extra closes)...:

```
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);

    int id = fork();

    if(id == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execvp("ls", (char*[]){"ls", "-l", NULL});
    }
    else
    {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execvp("tail", (char*[]){"tail", "-n", "2", NULL});
        waitpid(id, NULL, 0);
    }

    return 0;
```